# Creating Unit Tests for first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing

I am creating a new project using asp.net mvc , entity framework 6 and visual studio 2013.  I would like to create Tests straight from the start, else they never get created, but i am unsure about when and what to test.

In my solution i have the following projects

Data - My EF Context and the Configuration files to map entities to database
Entities - My POCO objects
Services - Contains my business logic for each entity.  Loads and saves data to my ef context
Web - WebApi and MVC Website

Now do i need to add a Test project for the Data project?  Part of me says "yes of course" because i want to make sure that data is being saved in the correct place, but then another part of me thinks that this will probably be repeated in the Services test project?

Here is a basic test i put together, but is it a good test, or pointless?

```
[TestClass]
public class CompanyTest
{
    private MyContext _context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // set our context
        _context = new MyContext();

        // add test data
        var companies = GetTestData();

        // save data
        companies.ForEach(s => _context.Companies.Add(s));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        var companies = _context.Companies.ToList();

        // remove all companies
        companies.ForEach(s => _context.Companies.Remove(s));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddCompanies_ShouldReturnTwo()
    {
        // get data
        var companies = _context.Set<Company>().ToList();

        // check values
        Assert.AreEqual(2, companies.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCompany_CheckDataInEachField()
    {
        var companies = _context.Set<Company>().ToList();
        Company company;

        // first company
        company = companies[0];

        Assert.AreEqual("ABC Construction", company.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC001", company.Reference);
        Assert.AreEqual("10-15 TemplateStreet", company.Street);
        Assert.AreEqual("Brierley Hill", company.Town);
        Assert.AreEqual("Somerset", company.County);
        Assert.AreEqual("England", company.Country);
        Assert.AreEqual("TY1 1AB", company.Postcode);

        // second company
        company = companies[1];

        Assert.AreEqual("Baseline Design", company.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("BAD0023", company.Reference);
        Assert.AreEqual("23-25 Hedlyn Road", company.Street);
        Assert.AreEqual("Oxford", company.Town);
        Assert.AreEqual("Oxford", company.County);
        Assert.AreEqual("England", company.Country);
        Assert.AreEqual("OX1 4FG", company.Postcode);
    }

    private List<Company> GetTestData()
    {
        // companies
        return new List<Company>
        {
            new Company{ Name="ABC Construction", Reference="ABC001", Street="10-15 TemplateStreet", Town="Brierley Hill", County="Somerset", Country="England", Postcode="TY1 1AB",DateAdded=DateTime.Now},
            new Company{ Name="Baseline Design", Reference="BAD0023", Street="23-25 Hedlyn Road", Town="Oxford", County="Oxford", Country="England", Postcode="OX1 4FG",DateAdded=DateTime.Now}
        };

    }
}
```

So will i just need Test projects for Services and Web?

If anyone knows of good reference material to explain when and how you should setup tests, please let me know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too wide to elaborate a good answer, my personal approach is to test every layer of the application, for sure the data and service layer.
In service layer the goal should be to test the business logic correctness, so the data usually should be mocked or faked, isolating the layer.
As I mentioned before there are a lot of ways to test an application, even if you want to test your javascript, to give you an idea take a look at this series of post:

- [Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern, Entity Framework, Unit
  Testing, Autofac IoC Container and ASP.NET MVC - Part 1](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)
- [Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern, Entity Framework, Unit
  Testing, Autofac IoC Container and ASP.NET MVC - Part 2](http://techbrij.com/autofac-ioc-container-asp-net-mvc-di)
- [Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern, Entity Framework, Unit
  Testing, Autofac IoC Container and ASP.NET MVC - Part 3](http://techbrij.com/unit-testing-asp-net-mvc-controller-service)
- [Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern, Entity Framework, Unit
  Testing, Autofac IoC Container and ASP.NET MVC - Part 4](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-testing-ioc-di-asp-net-mvc)

or start from msdn :

[Chapter 13: Unit Testing Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404088.aspx)

There are also a lot of books and videos on this topic, just take your time, it's not an easy learning curve, but is a must have knowledge on your developer tool belt

Comment: I appreciate it maybe a bit vage, but you kinda get what i mean.  Bit new to testing but just dont want to miss an important part of unit testing, or do it completely the wrong way. Thanks for the references